# Can we create a W state of n qubits with constant circuit depth using mid circuit measurements?

Tags: quantum-circuit, state-preparation

I saw this post where the GHZ state with many qubits (here 6) can be made by performing some mid circuit measurements in constant circuit depth: [Depth circuit optimization for 6-qubits GHZ state](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26276/depth-circuit-optimization-for-6-qubits-ghz-state)

I was wondering if mid-circuit measurements could help with creating a $W$ state in constant circuit depth. I'd like to constrict it to quantum computers that have limited connectivity, like a chain of qubits or some tiling layout like IBM quantum computers.

To give an example, for $n=4$ up to normalization, we have:

$$|W_4\rangle = |1000\rangle + |0100\rangle + |0010\rangle + |0001\rangle \,.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 4.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.14840.pdf) seems to answer your question positively. Section 4.3 of the same paper also shows how to do this for Dicke-states, the generalization of W-states.